# Don't get Data from Firestore on my TextView

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I tryed to show up text on the TextView which i'm saved with the saveQuote methode on Firestore, but just recieve null. I'm also had some problems by doing this with the "normal" database from Firebase. I definded the OnClick mthode for the buttons on the xml. Can someone maybe tell me how to fix that problem ? My logcat say "E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module", "GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!" and " Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position".

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final String TAG = "InspiringQuote";
    public static final String AUTHOR_KEY = "author";
    public static final String QUOTE_KEY = "quote";
    private TextView textViewData;

    private DocumentReference mDocRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document("sampleData/inspiration");
    TextView mQuoteTextView;
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();


    private CollectionReference noteRef = db.collection("inspiration");


    private Toolbar toolbar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //mQuoteTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_data);
        textViewData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_data);
        //Toolbar Options
        //toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.testToolbar);

//setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //getSupportActionBar().setTitle("HomePage");
        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //


    }





    public void saveQuote(View view){
        EditText quoteView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextQuote);
        EditText authorVIew = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAuthor);
        String quoteText = quoteView.getText().toString();
        String authorText = authorVIew.getText().toString();


        if (quoteText.isEmpty() || authorText.isEmpty()){return;}
        Map<String, Object> dataToSave = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        dataToSave.put("QUOTE_KEY", quoteText);
        dataToSave.put("AUTHOR_KEY", authorText);
        mDocRef.set(dataToSave).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Document has been saved");
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Document was not saved", e);
            }
        });
    }

    public void loadNote(View v){
        mDocRef.get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                        if(documentSnapshot.exists()){
                            String title = documentSnapshot.getString(QUOTE_KEY);
                            String description = documentSnapshot.getString(AUTHOR_KEY);

                            //Map<String, Object> note = documentSnapshot.getData();

                            textViewData.setText("Title" + title + "\n" + "Description: " + description);

                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Document does not exits", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());

                    }
                });

    }
}
```

[In the imgae you can see that im recieving "null"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4fhb.png)

Comment: Not sure about this but try - String title = documentSnapshot.getString("QUOTE_KEY"); and same for the Author_key... probably need to declare a string.

Comment: What do you exactly mean ? I did this in the loadNote methode.

Comment: Now i understood you.THANK YOU it works now !!

Comment: I've added the answer, can you please accept it to take it off the unanswered question list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment

```
String title = documentSnapshot.getString("QUOTE_KEY");
String description = documentSnapshot.getString("AUTHOR_KEY");
```

In your code, when you are adding the values, you are declaring a string value. However, when you are retrieving the values, you have declared string variable with different value. Therefore, it can't find what you are looking for.